# Passing object to child component loses its properties and methods

Tags: reactjs

**I have App.js that has a component in it where I pass down props:**

```
let chess = new Chess();

// lots of code...
console.log("chess in App.js", chess);

return <ChildComponent chess={chess} />;
```

The ChildComponent.js receives this prop as follows:

```
const ChildComponent = (chess) => {
  console.log("chess", chess);
};
```

When I inspect that in Chrome, I get this:

[image: Console image]

So, I am somehow losing the object detail when I pass it down as props. Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It needs to be in a `{}` because it's inside a `props` object**

```
const ChildComponent = ({ chess }) => {
  console.log("chess", chess);
};
```

**OR**

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  console.log("chess", props.chess);
};
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Ryan, you have just saved me a ton of time! I've spent so long on this the last few days trying to work out what was wrong. Does that mean whenever you pass down props, if you directly specify them like I have, you must use { }?

Comment: I'm super happy to hear that! Yes! Because everything you passed down to the child component will all be in a `props` object (functional component) so you will need to use  [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the params or direct access as I wrote there.

Comment: Keep it up! We are here to help

Answer (score 1):

Your code, log the `props` object,

try this

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
    console.log('chess', props.chess)
}
```

or

```
const ChildComponent = ({chess}) => {
console.log('chess', chess)
}
```